# Rails 2.3.8 multiple select not returning array, even with <select name='foo[]' multiple='multiple'>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, select, form-helpers

I admit to being a bit stumped on this, since I've been doing rails for some time.
I'm trying to get an array of values in `params[]` from a multiple-select combobox.

This is rails 2.3.5 and ruby 1.8.6 (I know, I know).

The generated html is:

```
 <select id="shows_" multiple="multiple" name="shows[]">
    <option value="5">A Grand Night For Singing (Jan - Feb 2007)</option>
    <option value="6">Who's Afraid of Virginia Woolf? (Mar - Apr 2007)</option>
  ...more options...
 </select>
```

Note that the select tag's name ends in '[]' and the 'multiple' option is set.
If I set a debug breakpoint at the top of the controller action and look at `params[:shows]`:

```
(rdb:62) p params[:shows]
["17,18,19"]
```

The captured values are correct, but i had expected `["17","18","19"]`, I.E. an array of N elements rather than an array of a single element consisting of N comma-separated values.

I could easily code around this, but I'm baffled since I'm pretty sure this used to work and the behavior I'm expecting is the documented behavior.  Any ideas?

Comment: I looked at http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/select_tag#691-sending-an-array-of-multiple-options and concur that your output looks right. I even tried it on a Rails 2.3.11 project and it worked as you expect. Does it work in 2.3.8 if you just make some shit up in the way presented on apidock?

Comment: correction, i'm on 2.3.5 not 2.3.8.  i've actually followed the stack trace down to ActionController::Dispatcher.call() and params['show'] has the above value even at that point in the call.

Answer (score 0):

The params are parsed by `Rack::Request` and `Rack::Utils`. You should have a look at [this](https://github.com/rack/rack/blob/master/lib/rack/request.rb) classes. Be aware though that the link does not necessarily point to the version of Rack you are using.